# Laravel replicate() function is not working for model collection

Tags: php, collections, model, laravel-5.1

i have facing a problem at laravel.

**I want to replicate/clone of collection after apply filter the collection.**

### code is below:

```
/* Scope function */         
    $plansFilterIndexes=Plans::PlansFilterFields();
     $planFilters=Plans::FilterFieldsSerial($query);
     /* Create Plans collection */

     $PlansAll=Plans::all();

    /* Plans Filter by url 
     * here checking $planFilter  indexes IS AVALIABLE AT 
     *  DEFINED  INDEX $plansFilterIndexes
     */
    $query = null;
        foreach($planFilters as $eachIndexKey => $eachIndexValue):
        echo $eachIndexKey.'------'.$eachIndexValue.'<br/>';
        if(array_search($eachIndexKey, $plansFilterIndexes) != false):

            $PlansAll = $PlansAll->where($eachIndexKey, $eachIndexValue);
        endif;
    endforeach;
    //dd($PlansAll);
    /* Clone collection into new once for copy */

    $PlansAllClone =$PlansAll->replicate();
    dd($PlansAllClone);
```

Try with [Clone an Eloquent object including all relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895126/clone-an-eloquent-object-including-all-relationships)  solution  but did not get result

**Show error:** `Method replicate does not exist.`

It not working.

**Question:**

*Why $PlansAllClone =$PlansAll->replicate(); is failed to give result.
and if it not possiable ,show i will achieve it.*

Answer (score 1):

Replicate is a method for cloning a model into a new non existing instance not for cloning a Collection.

replicate is used like this:

```
$newPlansInstance = Plans::replicate();
```

It can except an optional argument which is an array of exceptions.

What exactly are you trying to accomplish ?