# Laravel 5 Duplicate/Clone an DB Table. Products Cloning

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I want clone Products from my Database with an Button click.

Example:

In my Product List i have create an Item successful.
I want now add an second similar Item but dont want create an new Product and fill out the fields again (Takes time). I want now add an Button in my Laravel 5 Store where Duplicate or Clone the item where i have created before successful.

Just an new Database table with an other Product ID but all other the same info.

Whats the best way to do this?

Many Thanks

Comment: Does the Product have relationships? If so, do they need to be maintained?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent ORM replicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021239/laravel-eloquent-orm-replicate)

Comment: Please add some sample code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Eloquent you have a function `replicate()`, this will "clone" the object including relations.

Sample:

```
$product = Product::find(1);
$newProduct = $product->replicate();
$newProduct->save();
```