# Replicate Eloquent in Laravel with changing some columns

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, replicate

I'm using the replicate eloquent and it doesn't work on me. Replicate the row in database with changing some columns and it will save by clicking the button, can you please help me?
My coding for controller

```
   public function newpayrolls(Request $request, $id){
    $newpay = Payroll::find($id);
    $newpay = $newpay->replicate();
    $newpay->id = $new_id;
    $newpay->data = $new_data;
    $newpay->save();
     return redirect("/payroll");
```

Coding for my blade.php

```
 <button class ="btn btn-primary btnd" type="submit" value="Submit">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left small"></span> Save as 
 new Payroll
    </button>
    </div>
```

And this is my route

```
Route::get('/viewpayrolls/{id}','PayrollController@newpayrolls');
```

Comment: You are going to have to provide a lot more detail to receive any help. Please review [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: If the above code is really your controller then you have 2 variables that are undefined. `$new_id` and `$new_data`

Comment: Here's an example, including relationships: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021239/laravel-eloquent-orm-replicate

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Eloquent ORM replicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021239/laravel-eloquent-orm-replicate)