# Laravel - How to clone a relationship pivot with its attributes?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a many to many relationship in laravel with a pivot object/table.
I want to create a copy of one entry in this table, mantaining all the pivot properties (I have extra attributes for the relationship) and creating a new id.

Is it possible with laravel or should I just hack some raw sql into the database?

Comment: Can you show some example, what you want to do?

Answer (score 6):

In Laravel 5.4, if you want to clone a many-to-many Model, including its relationships and extra attributes in the pivot table, you need to amend the original solution provided in https://stackoverflow.com/a/34032304/309383 like so:

```
$model = User::find($id);

$model->load('invoices');

$newModel = $model->replicate();
$newModel->push();

// Once the model has been saved with a new ID, we can get its children
foreach ($newModel->getRelations() as $relation => $items) {
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        // Now we get the extra attributes from the pivot tables, but
        // we intentionally leave out the foreignKey, as we already 
        // have it in the newModel
        $extra_attributes = array_except($item->pivot->getAttributes(), $item->pivot->getForeignKey());
        $newModel->{$relation}()->attach($item, $extra_attributes);
    }
}
```

Note that this only applies to many-to-many relationships with pivot tables.